# Bootstrap .modal('hide') not working internet explorer 11 Object.keys: argument is not an Object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, internet-explorer-11, partial-views

I have use bootstrap model pop-up with MVC 5 partial view.

I am getting issue in Internet explorer 11, when I would like to try to open model popup then it  gives me error like

> SCRIPT5007: Object.keys: argument is not an Object
>
> File: bootstrap.min.js, Line: 6, Column: 585
>
> on code  $('#loginModal').modal('hide');

Just for info, I have open one "Sign in" pop-up and from it i would like to open "sign Up", it means open new pop-up from already open model pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in Bootstrap. Check this bug [report](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/26327)

> I have open one "Sign in" pop-up and from it i would like to open
>   "sign Up", it means open new pop-up from already open model pop-up.

This is not possible.

From Bootstrap [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

> Bootstrap only supports one modal window at a time. Nested modals
>   aren’t supported as we believe them to be poor user experiences.

**What you can do**

Close the SignIn modal and open the SignUp modal.

Comment: let me explain you in some more detail, I have one login popup and in that i also provide one link called "Sign up/register here". i have already open login popup but when user click on "Sign up/register here", login popup close and then open "Sign up/register here", see my code it will help you CODE :                                                function ShowSignupPopup() {
        $('#loginModal').modal('hide');
        $(document.body).addClass('modal-open');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#SignupModal').modal('show');
        }, 400);
    }

Comment: Any reason why you are doing this ? $(document.body).addClass('modal-open');

Comment: I am using .NET MVC 5 and login pop up need to access from whole site, thats why i put it in _Layout page.

Comment: @Divyeshbrevity this looks like a bug in Bootstrap in IE11, I have updated the bug report link in the answer.

Comment: Which link you have updated?  and in short it will not possible in IE11, is it so?

Comment: Try to use Bootstrap 4.0 or 4.1.1 instead of 4.1.0